# Insurance for car rental

Tags: insurance, car-insurance

I'm trying to find the best way to have a good insurance coverage when renting a car without a credit card or car insurance.

Here is my situation:

- I've arrived 6 months ago in the US, and am currently building my credit score (now it is 656)
- I only have a one US credit card with a small ($300) line.
- I don't have any car and so no car insurance.
- I have a renter insurance but this does not cover anything when renting a vehicle.

My problem is every time I rent a car, I have to buy the CDW coverage - because I can't use my credit card with such a small credit line - and a liability insurance - because I don't have a car insurance.
Last time this has tripled my rental price.

Do you know a way to get the same coverage car rental agencies offer without paying that much?

Also, I'd like to rent more with peep-to-peer (turo.com) or shared (zipcar) services.
But from what I found, these companies offers minimum - state required - CDW coverage and no liability coverage.

Is there a way to buy a separated insurance coverage for this companies?

Or maybe it is not worth adding an insurance with these companies?